How to access media-service notification controls with UiAutomator?
I'm basically starting a foreground media-service from an activity and then move the activity to Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED. ServiceTestRule is not really sufficient for testing bound services, which may require testing the bound service notification.
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest extends BaseActivityTestCase {

    protected ActivityScenario<MainActivity> mScenario;

    @Before
    public void setupTest() {
        this.setScenario(this.activityScenarioRule.getScenario());
        this.getScenario().onActivity(activity -> { /* ... */ });
    }

    @Test
    public void testActivityLifecycle() {

        /* Destroy the Activity. */
        this.getScenario().moveToState(Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED);

        /* TODO: Use UiAutomator to click media-controls. */
    }

    @NonNull
    protected ActivityScenario<MainActivity> getScenario() {
        return this.mScenario;
    }

    protected void setScenario(@NonNull ActivityScenario<MainActivity> scenario) {
        this.mScenario = scenario;
    }

    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        this.getScenario().close();
        super.tearDown();
    }
}

How to access media-service notification controls with UiAutomator?

I've wrote some methods, in order to get a handle to the media-service notification.
a) This open the notification panel - and returns the notification panel ScrollView:
static final UiDevice mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());

UiObject openNotificationPanel() {
    synchronized (mDevice) {
        if (mDevice.openNotification()) {
            mDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg("com.android.systemui")), 10000);
            UiObject item = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.android.systemui:id/notification_stack_scroller"));
            assertTrue(item.exists());
            return item;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

b) This returns child-node android:id/notification_media_content from the ScrollView:
UiObject getMediaServiceNotification(@NonNull UiObject scrollView) {
    try {
        UiObject item = scrollView
            .getChild(new UiSelector().resourceId("android:id/notification_media_content"));
        assertTrue(item.exists());
        return item;
    } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG,"UiObjectNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

c) And this ultimately clicks the media-action button inside the notification.
The relevant child-nodes are: mediaActions, mainColumn, mediaProgress.
Boolean clickMediaActionAtIndex(@NonNull UiObject notification, int index) {
    try {

        UiObject mediaActions = notification.getChild(new UiSelector().resourceId("android:id/media_actions"));
        assertTrue(mediaActions.exists());

        UiObject mainColumn = notification.getChild(new UiSelector().resourceId("android:id/notification_main_column"));
        assertTrue(mainColumn.exists());

        UiObject mediaProgress = notification.getChild(new UiSelector().resourceId("android:id/notification_media_progress"));
        assertTrue(mediaProgress.exists());

        if (index < mediaActions.getChildCount()) {
            UiObject mediaAction = mediaActions.getChild(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.ImageButton").index(index));
            assertTrue(mediaAction.exists());
            mediaAction.click();
            return true;
        }
    } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG,"UiObjectNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}


And the test-case looks about alike this:
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest extends TestCase {

    @Test
    public void testActivityLifecycle() {

        /* Destroy the Activity. */
        this.getScenario().moveToState(Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED);

        /* UiAutomator: Media Service Notification. */
        UiObject scrollView = this.openNotificationPanel();
        UiObject notification = this.getMediaServiceNotification(scrollView);

        /* Click Media Action: Play/Pause. */
        assertTrue(this.clickMediaActionAtIndex(notification, 2));
    }
}

